# Borel-Cantelli lemma for general measure spaces (those with infinite measure)

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, measure-theory

The Borel-Cantelli lemma is often stated for a probability space or spaces with finite measure.

But it seems to me that it still holds if the space $X$ is of infinite measure. I seem to be able to prove this.

Is there any reason that Borel-Cantelli is usually associated with probability spaces?

Comment: Which direction?  The easy direction, not requiring independence, same proof, right?  $\sum \mu(E_n) < \infty \Longrightarrow \mu(\limsup E_n)=0$. For the hard direction, first you have to define independence, I guess.

Comment: Reading the OP again, it seems that the question is: "I can prove Borel Cantelli for any measure space; why is it often only stated for finite measure spaces?"  I think.  Well, Wikipedia does state it in generality: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#General_measure_spaces  I can only assume that the answer is: because the natural interpretation of this result is "probabilistic".

Comment: The first Borel-Cantelli lemma takes place in a finite measure space WLOG. I agree with Gerald that the second Borel-Cantelli lemma is not really meaningful outside of a probabilistic context because it's not clear what independence is supposed to mean. 

Comment: And in fact no need to assume "finite measure" when the hypothesis is $\sum \mu(E_n) < \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

I think the measure is needed to be finite. Consider the counterexample as follows:

Let $X=\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathcal{M}$ be the set of all subsets of $X.$ Construct a map $\mu:\mathcal{M} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as $\mu(\left\{0\right\})=1,\ \mu(\left\{x\right\})=-1$ for all $x \ne 0$ and $\mu(\emptyset)=0.$ Extend $\mu$ to a map on $\mathcal{M}$ by using the disjoint countably additive property. Then we can trivially check that $\mu$ is a measure on $X$ which is signed but not finite.

Let $E_k=\left\{0,k\right\}$ for all $k \ge 1.$ Then we can easily compute that $\mu(E_k)=0$ for all $k,$ which implies that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(E_k)=0<\infty.$ But $\mu(\limsup_{k \rightarrow \infty}E_k)=1$ since $\limsup_{k \rightarrow \infty}E_k=\left\{0\right\},$ which gives that contradiction!

Comment: Borel-Cantelli is only dealing with positive measures, not signed ones...

Comment: I think for signed measures the hypothesis should be $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|\mu(E_k)|<\infty$.